# Split text into Columns with Flutter Pdf

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages

I'm using the pdf/pdf.dart package to create a PDF document that displays long paragraphs of text in an article-like format. I'm running into an issue where I cannot figure out how to format the pdf in a way where text spans across multiple columns.

I have an input as a big String of text, and I need it to be formatted into two columns to span across multiple pages. I have only been able to span the text in 1 column across multiple pages (using the column and richtext pdf widgets).

To clarify here is an example of the format I have been able to achieve (notice the text is in a single column): https://www.ohchr.org/sites/default/files/UDHR/Documents/UDHR_Translations/eng.pdf

Here is what I am hoping to achieve (notice the text spans across multiple columns on the same page): https://constitutioncenter.org/media/files/constitution.pdf

Is this possible with the package I am using, if not are there any packages anyone knows of that can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

To calculate size constraints.maxWidth/2, you can use LayoutBuilder and ConstrainedBox as follows:

```
  pw.Widget _termsAndConditionsLong(pw.Context context) {
   return pw.LayoutBuilder(
    builder: ( context, constraints) {
      return pw.ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: pw.BoxConstraints(minHeight: constraints!.maxHeight, minWidth: constraints.maxWidth),
          child: pw.Wrap(
            crossAxisAlignment: pw.WrapCrossAlignment.start,
            children: [

              for(dynamic text in [1,2,3,5,5])
                pw.Container(
                  margin: const pw.EdgeInsets.only(right: 10, left: 10),
                  width: (constraints.maxWidth/2)-20,
                  height: constraints.maxHeight,
                  decoration: pw.BoxDecoration(
                    border: pw.Border(top: pw.BorderSide(color: accentColor)),
                  ),
                  padding: const pw.EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, bottom: 2),
                  child: pw.Text(
                    TermsAndConditions,
                    textAlign: pw.TextAlign.justify,
                    style: const pw.TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 8,
                      //lineSpacing: 3,
                      color: _darkColor,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
            ],
          ));
    });}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I am a bit confused though. The argument you are using for the `pw.Text()` is called `TermsAndConditions` which is not defined within your for loop. And the variable `text` you defined in your for loop is never used... Also, I dont just need to just move text objects to differnt columns, I need text to span across if there isn't enough room in the current column for it. I don't see where you answer does that.

Comment: I just logged in, I hope you found the solution. TermsAndConditions is just a text variable you can put whatever you want there. I suggested using **LayoutBuilder** to find out the dimensions available on the page. From the **constraints.maxWidth** allows you to define the dimensions of the elements.